# How to change Base URl of a website - Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have a website based on laravel 5.4. The site is working fine on my localhost. But when I upload it on my shared hosting. It is giving me an error

```
"at FileViewFinder->findInPaths('welcome', array('C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\lrl\\resources\\views'))"
```

C:\xampp\htdocs\lrl\resources\views this is my localhost URL. How can I changed this URl. I have made changes in .env file and I put all the files of public folder at root directory. Also I changed Appserviceprovider.php file.

namespace App\Providers;

```
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Schema;
use DB;
use View;
use Request;
```

I also cleared the cache but still i am getting this error shown in screenshot[image]

Comment: do you have written any code in controller for `welcome` ?

Comment: No, I don't have written any code for welcome. It is by default.

Comment: search in your root folder for this word `welcome` ?

Comment: welcome view file is there in my resource folder

Comment: also I have this in my web.php Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run `php artisan config:cache`

`C:\xampp\htdocs\lrl\resources\views` is cached in your config file. So, you must clear config cache by run artisan command `php artisan config:cache`.

Comment: your answer fixed the problem I've been losing my mind over for hours! So bloody simple!!!

Answer (score 0):

Clear you `route` cache

`php artisan route:cache`

Clear all if still not work

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear
php artisan view:clear
```